# Tag rename (rice)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a tag [rice](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rice), which I think is badly named.  It is applied to three questions, all of which are about Rice's theorem and not, for example, about Henry Rice himself. If you don't already know that Rice's theorem is a thing, the tag "rice" is pretty much meaningless and near-impossible to Google.

Is there any way we can rename it to, say, "rices-theorem"? (Apostrophes aren't allowed, it seems.) That's a much more meaningful description and, even if you don't know what Rice's theorem is, at least you have something to work from.

Comment: Be thankful that the important theorems of Ivor Spelt and Peter Wheat aren't better-known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merged [rice](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rice) into [rice-theorem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rice-theorem) which someone created in the meantime.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest "rice-theorem". It would be easily found by automatch, and "rices" is not a word (in this context).

Comment: Actually, "rices" is a word but I don't see how that's relevant. "rice" vs "rices" is essentially a question of how to deal with not being allowed to use apostrophes in tag names. My own feeling is that "rices theorem" is closer to the intended meaning than "rice theorem".  ("Rices" can be a noun, in the sense of "There are several rices, such as long-grain and short-grain" and one might refer to Mr and Mrs Rice as "the Rices"; "rice" is also a verb, meaning to mash potato by forcing int through a fine mesh and, informally, to "pimp up" ones car.)

Comment: That's why I said "in this context". I know "rices" is a word :-) Anyway, just a suggestion.

Comment: OK -- I see what you mean, now.